# VSTS - Stuck in a endless loop of publishing a new, existing local project

Tags: git

Visual Studio Team Server

1. I created a local project.
2. I selected the Microsoft plugin for team services
3. I published the project to Team Services.
4. I made some changes to the local version.
5. I cannot push a commit.

I get a message from VS:

> The team project '(Project name here)' already exists. Please choose
>   another name for the team project.

Checking the online version of Team Services the project exists but no files have been sync'd. If I try to create a Commit I cannot. I am struck on the "Publish Repository" page. If I click "Publich Repository" It looks like a error flashes up on screen but it is too fast to read.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select **Push to Remote Repository** now - you have already created a repo.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you. I guess you have to login to Team online to get the remote URL? Is there any way to get that through Visual Studio?

Comment: I think that should be automatically available to you once you've signed in - pushing to a repo kind of links them together. Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio and this link: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Visual-Studio